# oracle query for the case of branching

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have several tables are as follows

```
orders table
-----------------------------
 id_order         no_order
-----------------------------
   1               0000001
   2               0000002
   3               0000003
-----------------------------

item_order table
-------------------------------------------
 id_item_order    id_order   product_name
-------------------------------------------
    1               2         Product X
    2               2         Product Y
    3               2         Product Z
    4               2         Product W
-------------------------------------------

faktur_pemuatan table
-------------------------------------------
 id_faktur_pemuatan     id_item_order
-------------------------------------------
  1                      1
-------------------------------------------
```

a orders have few item_order as seen in the table above. if the data from table item_order are not included in the table faktur_pemuatan, the data from which orders id_item_order item_order with 1, 2, 3, 4 will appear, but if there is any of the data item_order contained in the table faktur_pemuatan, eg. item_order with id_item_order eg '1 'has contained in the table faktur_pemuatan, then the data will not show up orders. how to solve this problem, what should use branching if or case, if so how to query for the above problems. please help me. I am very grateful if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    O.*, I.*
FROM orders O
    JOIN item_order I
        ON O.id_order = I.id_order
    LEFT JOIN faktur_pemuatan F
        ON I.id_item_order = F.id_item_order
WHERE F.id_faktur_pemuatan IS NULL
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c08b/3)**

Comment: not work, if there data of item_order contained in faktur_pemuatan table, then data item_order is not show

Comment: @user1878292 What you mean? Can you add some test data in SQL Fiddle and tell me your desired result?